# No method summary displayed outside main xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

When I create methods and use them later on, I can see my summary when I MouseOver the method while typing. But when the method is written in another file, it never shows the summary. If I type the method within the same file, stuff is shown, otherwise nothing is shown.

I have read other questions about this and tried checking the "XML documentation file" in the build tab, restarted Visual Studio 2015 but nothing changed (though the XML file is created in the Debug folder, were I execute my stuff).

How can I make my summaries work from within other files? I am not creating a dll file, I am creating a simple basic WPF application (.exe). I am talking about methods that are written by me within the .exe project that do not show a summary when the method is written in another file, for instance in a folder "Interfaces" or "Helper classes" and then another .cs file. There is also an XML file located in the same folder as the .exe file (Debug folder) but no difference.

So for instance, I have a folder "Interfaces" in my project. In this folder is a file called ServerConnect.cs that has a method named "SomeMethod()". My summary is like this:

```
///<summary>
///<para>Some text</para>
///</summary>
```

If I want to use this method from within ServerConnect.cs, I will see the summary if I mouseover the method name. But if I use this method somewhere else, for instance in Mainwindow.xaml.cs, I don't see any summaries.

Comment: Note that in addition to enabling the "XML documentation file" option, you need to make sure the XML file is deployed alongside the DLL when you reference it elsewhere. If you are doing all that and still can't get it to work, then you will need to be a _lot_ more specific about how your projects are building and used.

Comment: I am not creating a DLL file, just a simple WPF application. I still have no clue how to fix this. This question is not duplicate, please give me a source of the duplicate question, this question is not about creating a DLL, its within the same executable, just a seperate file like "Interfaces\ConnectServer.cs"..

Comment: XML comments within the same assembly work fine whether or not you generate the XML documentation file. It just works. In all files within the assembly. If it doesn't work for you, then there's something wrong but your question doesn't provide any information about what that could be. Maybe you haven't typed the XML comment itself correctly, or maybe you need to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio, or maybe you have installed an extension that is interfering. There are a number of questions already on Stack Overflow with the same vague "XML comments aren't working"; check those first.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your help! Perhaps then I do have a conflicting extension installed somewhere, I'll check that out.

Comment: Mmm, too bad it didn't work, I uninstalled all non-microsoft extensions, restarted VS, but no effect... :-(

Comment: I fixed it: in case of an interface, the summary should be placed on each method declaration within the interface instead of at the method code itself. Problem solved!

Comment: Yes, it's true...you do need to author the XML comments correctly for them to show up anywhere. Note that when authored incorrectly, they won't show up even in the same file where they are written.